# Android - Auto Fill fields upon selecting/entering a field

Tags: android, autocomplete

How to AutoFill other fields upon Selecting a particular field in Android App.

For Example, I have fields to enter name, emailId, phoneNo of users.
Also I have stored the informations of registered users.
If the users will select/enter their names, the emailId and the phoneNo has to be AutoFilled from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

When name is entered then fetch emailID and PhoneNO of the user and use

```
editText.setText(emailID);
editText.setText(phoneNO);
```